# async model binding asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, json.net, model-binding

I'm working on a "bursty" Asp.Net Core 2.2 site in which we have long periods of predictable loads but occasionally we will have bursts of traffic. After some of these bursts one of the servers will go spastic and just keep adding threads as fast as it can to the threadpool (ca 1 per sec) until it has reached the max of approx 32k threads (we normally run with about 40 worker threads, so 32k seems excessive) and then becomes unresponsive

As I understand it, that the problem is that we in our mostly async codebase do some thread-blocking and i guess that if all the threads become blocked simultaneously we enter a bad state in which new threads get added slowly and starts out handling new traffic (which is constantly pouring in) instead of helping out the blocked threads until they themselves have been blocked, since new threads are only trickling in at about 1 per sec we never get a critical mass of free threads so they can free any of the growing number of blocked threads.

Now I have tried my darndest tracking down all places in code we do sync stuff and replacing it with async, I have used Ben Adams blocking detector, I have tried running with just 1 worker thread in the thread pool to see where the site hangs, I have set Kestrel to disallow synchronous operations on the request/response and I believe I have removed all the culprits in my own code, but for api-operations where we use asp.net core model binding from JSON-body we get InvalidOperationException:

> "Synchronous operations are disallowed. Call ReadAsync or set
>   AllowSynchronousIO to true instead."

with stacktrace:

```
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.HttpRequestStreamReader.ReadIntoBuffer()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.HttpRequestStreamReader.Read(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadData(Boolean append, Int32 charsRequired)
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
...
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonInputFormatter.<ReadRequestBodyAsync>d__17.MoveNext()--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
...
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder.<BindModelAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
```

Could this be the problem? How do we get async json model binding for Asp.Net Core 2.2